# Can someone help me in installing python package "Prophet" on windows 10

Tags: python-3.5

Can someone help me in installing python package "Prophet" on windows 10 . 
I tried installing python 3.5 and the dependency 'pystan' but yet I get below error.

> "The package setup script has attempted to modify files on your system that are not within the EasyInstall build area, and has been aborted.This package cannot be safely installed by EasyInstall, and may not support alternate installation locations even if you run its setup script by hand.Please inform the package's author and the EasyInstall maintainers to find out if a fix or workaround is available.
>   Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in c:\users\suman\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-aqoiqs\fbprophet\"`

Answer (score 3):

I spent a good two days on this issue, finally, I found the following solution

1) Download and install Anaconda 3 (for python 3.6)
2) Create an environment and call it whatever you like 
3) Run that environment   (which will open the command prompt) 
4) follow the following steps in command prompt : (commands are shown in bold)

**python -m pip install -U pip**
Requirement already up-to-date: pip in c:\users\william\anaconda3\envs\testtime\lib\site-packages

**conda install -c conda-forge pystan**
Fetching package metadata ...............
Solving package specifications: .

Package plan for installation in environment C:\Users\William\Anaconda3\envs\Testtime:

The following NEW packages will be INSTALLED:

```
backports:                     1.0-py36_1            conda-forge
backports.functools_lru_cache: 1.4-py36_1            conda-forge
ca-certificates:               2017.11.5-0           conda-forge
cycler:                        0.10.0-py36_0         conda-forge
cython:                        0.27.3-py36_0         conda-forge
freetype:                      2.7-vc14_1            conda-forge [vc14]
icc_rt:                        2017.0.4-h97af966_0
icu:                           58.2-vc14_0           conda-forge [vc14]
intel-openmp:                  2018.0.0-hd92c6cd_8
jpeg:                          9b-vc14_2             conda-forge [vc14]
libpng:                        1.6.34-vc14_0         conda-forge [vc14]
matplotlib:                    2.1.0-py36_0          conda-forge
mkl:                           2018.0.1-h2108138_4
numpy:                         1.13.3-py36ha320f96_0
openssl:                       1.0.2m-vc14_0         conda-forge [vc14]
pyparsing:                     2.2.0-py36_0          conda-forge
pyqt:                          5.6.0-py36_4          conda-forge
pystan:                        2.17.0.0-py36_vc14_0  conda-forge [vc14]
python-dateutil:               2.6.1-py36_0          conda-forge
pytz:                          2017.3-py_2           conda-forge
qt:                            5.6.2-vc14_1          conda-forge [vc14]
sip:                           4.18-py36_1           conda-forge
six:                           1.11.0-py36_1         conda-forge
tornado:                       4.5.2-py36_0          conda-forge
zlib:                          1.2.11-vc14_0         conda-forge [vc14]
```

**pip install fbprophet**

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if the same trick would work on Windows, anyways posting w.r.t what just worked on RHEL 7, f.w.i.w

Motivation was installing fbprophet using conda:

```
conda install -c conda-forge fbprophet
```

and, it could install **pystan==2.17.1.0** and **fbprophet==0.6**

So, the trick was:
uninstall the pystan package when you had earlier run pip3 install fbprophet, basically one needs to execute the following:

```
pip3 install pystan==2.17.1.0
pip3 install fbprophet==0.6
```

And one can thereby import fbprophet in python3 terminal, so working :)

Answer (score 1):

I also had several issues installing `prophet` on my Windows 10 machine using `conda` and `Python 3.7`.

The following steps made it work:

1. Create a fresh `conda` environment
2. Install `pystan` and other dependencies using `conda install numpy cython matplotlib scipy pandas -c conda-forge` (see https://pystan2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/windows.html#steps)
3. Install `prophet` using `conda install prophet -c conda-forge`

In then still had a numpy error `Importing the numpy c-extensions failed...` as described here: https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/troubleshooting-importerror.html But this was due to my IDE which is VS Code as I could successfully run my `prohet` model using the command line with the activated `conda` environment.

So please also make sure to test the installation from the command line in order to rule out that the error stems from you IDE.

Answer (score 0):

I currently have a fairly vanilla install of Python 3.5 on my Windows 10 machine that I setup using Anaconda.

I was able to install Prophet using the below command, that might work for you. Depending on how your installed Python you may need to run the below command in a cmd shell that was opened as administrator.

```
pip install prophet
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I was able to install with 'pip install prophet' as you said but the module doesn't get imported when importing in jupyter. 

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import Prophet
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-bd76fd529c16> in <module>()
      1 import pandas as pd
      2 import numpy as np
----> 3 import Prophet

ImportError: No module named Prophet

Answer (score 0):

Whenever I have tried to install fbprophet package multiple issues have come.I will suggest a few steps, hopefully they should work.

1. Close all existing Python / R running instances. If possible restart the machine. I have seen to work as few libraries / dependencies which I want to update might be getting used by existing running instances.
2. Use anaconda prompt.
3. First install pystan -

   ```
   `conda install pystan`
   ```
4. Now install fbprophet

   `'conda install -c conda-forge fbprophet`

Hopefully it should work for you. Also, ensure you have admin rights.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue and my solution was to:-

- Create a new environment with Python3.5

  - `conda create -n pht python=3.5 anaconda`
- Install Prophet using the command.

  - `conda install -c conda-forge fbprophet`

I didn't install 'gcc' although this was advised before installing Prophet.